# Handicap Coding : Print first n natural number in java only using if else , while loop and one variable n which stores input from user

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

Usual solution to this problem would be below

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = sc.nextInt();

int c = 1;
while (c<=n){
system.out.println(c);
++c;
}
```

But i do not want to use variable c anymore , is this possible to code without 2nd variable. I know this can be achievable thru recursion function, but i only want to code with while, if else. Kindly let me know if this is possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the order matter? Else you could just loop in reverse: `while(n > 0) {System.out.println(n);}`

Comment: @Lino that's an infinite loop, unless you meant `while(n > 0) {System.out.println(n--);}`

Comment: If we use `int` for natural numbers, then we still have half of the ints capacity to represent negative numbers. It is possible to use bit operations to store information about the current number in the range of negative numbers in our `int`. The idea is that for natural numbers only half of the `int` capacity is needed. The other half can be used as a second variable for storing the state of the cycle.

Comment: similar to what @chptr-one suggested, but just change the type of the variable `n` to `long` and use the upper 32 bits to keep track of the loop iteration: https://ideone.com/KSB1NK